# Twitter Bootstrap 2.0.4 Modal - How to apply modal fade in effect to a newly created modal class style?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-plugins, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am learning Web Design by myself and now I've started playing with twitter bootstrap's modal JavaScript plugin.

I've created a new modal class named modal-login, it's a login form inside a modal window. Things have been working good, but the fade effect/slide down does not work. The effect that bring down the modal box from top to center.

I don't have yet deep understanding of javascript and jQuery.

My question now is, can we edit the bootstrap-modal.js file, so that I may include my new modal class named modal-login and modal-register? so that it could take advantage of the modal fade in effect?

Comment: You definitely do not want to modify the bootstrap-model.js file.  You can extend the plugin or just use JS / jQuery in your project to fade in / out based on the class.

Also, since you're new to web design, check out http://jsfiddle.net/  It will help us identify your problems if you show us what you've done first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't need to edit the **bootstrap-modal.js** file.  You just need to add the `fade` class to your modals, and then add some CSS rules.

For example:

```css
.modal-login.fade {
  top: -25%;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, top 0.3s ease-out;
     -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, top 0.3s ease-out;
      -ms-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, top 0.3s ease-out;
       -o-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, top 0.3s ease-out;
          transition: opacity 0.3s linear, top 0.3s ease-out;
}

.modal-login.fade.in {
  top: 50%;
}
```

Even better would be if you still kept the plain `modal` class on your new one's, and just used your new classes to do overrides.  That way you could inherit the CSS above, without having to duplicate it.

Comment: Thank you for the input, but my problem is, I can only override the original modal my using !important. And I don't feel like using !important, that is why I've created a new class for a new modal box. The modal works fine, except that I've mentioned it, that the slide down effect does not work on my modal. Any hind by the way on how to override the orig modal with my modal class, without using !important?

Comment: Oh, another thing, I think I am referring to the slide down effect of the modal, NOT the fade effect. The slide down effect, I mean was the original modal effect, that brings down the modal from top to center screen. Top positioning were already applied to my new modal class, in my case it's top: 70%. I wish to post some reference image here, but I can't for now due to some restrictions on my newbie account.

Comment: @GaryDapogi Sorry, I made a mistake in my first post: you should not include `in` as a class on your modal initially.  Rather, you need to have that class will be added when you show it.  The "slide effect" is basically the difference between the CSS rules in `fade` and `in`, and with CSS transitions, tweens from the former to the latter.

Comment: @GaryDapogi A [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/y4XRR/3/) would also be really helpful. :D

Comment: @BrandonV, I will checkout the site, when I got the time. It seems to complicated to use at first.

Comment: merv, thanks to those codes above, that did the trick. Now I understood how the modal animation works (the slide down effect). So the .fade and .fade.in's declaration makes the animation effect, the slide from top to it's intended position. Thanks to you, I can play around with my modals. Gonna try left to center out.